# Error in database insertion operation in Php

Tags: php, database, insert, syntax-error

I am doing an insertion operation in PHP using functions. The error seems very trivial but i couldn't identify its source.

```
<?php

class DB_Insert{

public function insertLec($lecId,$csId,$date,$time,$update,$export)
{
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("attenmandb");
    $retval=mysql_query("INSERT INTO lecturetb(LecID, CSID, Date, Time, Updation, Export) VALUES($lecId,'$csId','$date','$time','$update','$export')",$con);
    if(! $retval)
    {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Success';
    }
}

$this->insertLec(1,'CST5','27-9-2014','11.30 to 12.30','No','No');
}

?>
```

Error looks like this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in DB_Insert.php on line 20
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->insertLec(1,'CST5','27-9-2014','11.30 to 12.30','No','No');
```

Is just floating in your class. It needs to be in the code that calls your class.

```
$insert = new DB_Insert();
$insert->insertLec(1,'CST5','27-9-2014','11.30 to 12.30','No','No');
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Answer (score 0):

Your have sequential code with your class definition, but not within a function. You need to move that function call outside the class:

```
} // end of class definition
  $dbInsert= new DB_Insert();
  $dbInsert->insertLec(1,'CST5','27-9-2014','11.30 to 12.30','No','No');
```

//edited to acknowledge previous answer as correct!
Yeah, like John said!